# Two random independent variables variance

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, variance

The earnings a merchant has is given by $Z=3X-Y-5$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with $\operatorname{Var}{(X)}=1$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=2$. What is the value of $\operatorname{Var}(Z)$ ?

I'm not sure where to start from, I should have the probability function of both of them to calculate the variance, so I'm lost.

Comment: "I should have the probability function of both of them to calculate the variance" Fortunately, you should not.

Answer (score 2):

We have a few rules for the variance:
\begin{align} \operatorname{Var}(aX+b) &= E[(aX+b)^2]-E[aX+b]^2 \\
&= a^2E[X^2] + 2abE[X] + b^2 - a^2E[X]^2 - 2abE[X]-b^2 \\
&= a^2\operatorname{Var}(X),
\end{align}
so constant shifts don't do anything, and rescaling gets squared. If $X,Y$ are independent, then
$$ E[XY]=E[X]E[Y], $$
so
\begin{align} \operatorname{Var}(X+Y) &= E[(X+Y)^2]-E[X+Y]^2 \\
&= E[X^2] + 2E[XY] + E[Y^2] - E[X]^2 - 2E[X]E[Y] - E[Y]^2 \\
&= \operatorname{Var}(X)+\operatorname{Var}(Y).
\end{align}
A combination of these is enough to calculate $\operatorname{Var}(Z)$ in terms of the given variances:
$$ \operatorname{Var}(Z) = \operatorname{Var}(3X-Y-5) = \operatorname{Var}(3X-Y) = 9\operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Var}(Y)  $$